# Using jQuery to load multiple files in the same div and overwrite previous ones loaded

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, laravel-4

I apologize in advance as I'm just starting out with this, and this likely could be something pretty simple.

What I'm trying to accomplish is when the page first loads I have an empty div (popBox). When I click on a link the div populates with a file I assigned.

However, currently if I want to click on a second link and overwrite that div's link1 content with link2's content nothing happens. I've searched around a bit and found a lot of posts suggesting using .live, but it looks like it's deprecated and replaced with .on. I tried both without much success. I defined my baseURL earlier in the document, and am using Laravel 4.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#addLink").on('click', function()
    {
        $("#popBox").load(baseURL + 'additem');
    });
    $("#cancelLink").on('click', function()
    {
        $("#popBox").load(baseURL + 'blank');
    });
});
```

My HTML looks like this.

```
div id="popBox"/div
```

I'd like it so once the first link is clicked and the content loaded in the "popBox" div I'm able to click the second link (which is inside the popBox) to have it overwrite anything in that div and load a blank document.

Any help that can get me going in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem then this should do the job:

```
$("#popBox").on('click', '#cancelLink', function()
{
    $("#popBox").load(baseURL + 'blank');
});
```

Declare this inside `document.ready` event handler, in other words, replace the second event handler which is, `$("#cancelLink").on('click' ...)` in your code with this (given above).

Answer (score -1):

The problem you are having is because the http request to your server for 'additem' is asynchronous, in other words the script does not stop and wait for a response before executing the next instruction (assigning the cancel link click event handler). As a result the cancel link does not exist when you are trying to assign the click event handler.

You need to use a callback function which will execute once the response has been recieved and the html has been injected into popBox.

See http://api.jquery.com/load/ and look at the 'complete' parameter.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#addLink").on('click', function()
    {
        $("#popBox").load(baseURL + 'additem', setupInternalPopBoxLinks);
    });
});

function setupInternalPopBoxLinks()
{
    $("#cancelLink").on('click', function()
    {
        $("#popBox").load(baseURL + 'blank', setupInternalPopBoxLinks);
    });

    // add any other links that might be loaded into the popBox here.
}
```

This is not the 'best' way to do this but it will work for your scenario and is probably the simplest to show what's going on.

I have not tested this as I am pressed for time but it should help.

Comment: Awesome, Mike. Thank you so much for explaining why that was. I tested it with what you provided and the script is working now.

Comment: It's not necessary to call `setupInternalPopBoxLinks` every time if delegated event handler was declared like in my answer.

Comment: You provided a solution without an explanation.